# .Net 4.0 Framework Causing Issue for aspnet_regiis during installation

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

We have a ASP.net 2.0 web app with an installer which appears to hit an issue with .Net Framework 4.0. This has occurred on XP and Windows 7. Seems to happen every time.

During the installation, we call aspnet_regiis for various tasks such as encrypting the web.config. If .Net 4 is installed this throws the error:

---

### aspnet_regiis.exe - .NET Framework Initialization Error

### Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application.

### OK

Running the same commands from the commandline works correctly.

Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Thanks,
Davy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by aspnet_regiis.exe not dealing with short (8.3) filenames in this scenario. The fix was simply to always supply the full version of the path.

Davy

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not running it from the correct folder. You have:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe
```

for ASP.NET 2.0 and:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe
```

for ASP.NET 4.0

Comment: Thanks for reply but it is definitely being run from the v2 folder.

Comment: And your application is targeting which CLR version? Also in IIS the application pool is targeting which CLR version?

Comment: We are targeting 2.0 and the 'App Pool' is set to this. I have added this version detail to the original question.